# Probability of counter being 23

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

This is a probability question. Suppose we start our journey from step number 0. We now toss a coin. If the result is a head, we add 3 to a counter. If the result is a tail, we add 2 to the counter. We now move to step number 1. We toss the coin again and depending on the result, we update the counter. We then move on to step number 2 and repeat the experiment and so on. The question is, when we arrive at step 10, what is the probability that the counter reads 23?
PS: I have had no clue while doing this. I have used normal counting methods which were too lengthy to proceed further.

Comment: Do you mean the counter to be $23$ after nine or ten tosses?

Comment: I mean the coin is tossed at 9 and then stopped, no more tosses.

Comment: But remember that the first coin toss it at position $0$, so there are $10$ tosses in total.

Comment: I am not sure from the wording whether the counter stuff happens $10$ times or $11$ times. Lean to $10$. We get $23$ if and only if there are $7$ twos and $3$ threes.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I don't see where the problem with the formulation is. We start at step $0$. We flip a coin, and then take a step, landing at $1$. We flip a coin, and then take another step, landing at $2$. The moment we arrive at step $10$ we will therefore have done $10$ coin tosses.

Comment: Arrive at can get confuted with do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So another way to see this is that you will always add $2$ to the counter, and then you flip a coin. If heads you add another $1$ to the counter and if tails you leave it.

In this interpretation, it's easy to see that after $10$ steps we have $20$ points on the counter guaranteed, plus one for each heads we got. We are flipping the coin $10$ times, and we want the probability that we get a total of three heads.

If you've heard about binomial probability, you will now know that the answer is
$$
\binom{10}{3}\cdot \left(\frac12\right)^3\left(\frac12\right)^7
$$
If you haven't heard about binomial probability, leave a comment, and I'll flesh out this answer a bit.

Note: The binomial coefficient $\binom{10}{3}$ might also be known as $_{10}C_3$ or $C(10, 3)$, depending on your textbook.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I took so much time to reply cuz I was wondering if the solution would be so straight forward but this made perfect sense. Thanks a lot @Arthur